# Inconsistent behavior with user_logout function

Tags: 8, users, redirection

For a drupal 8 site, I have a custom function that does the following:

It logs out the user and sends them to an external url

Inside the controller CustomController, I have:

```
function custom_logout(){
 if (\Drupal::currentUser()->isAuthenticated()) {
    user_logout();
    return new TrustedRedirectResponse('https://example.com');
 }
}
```

In the routing.yml

```
customl.clogout:
  path: '/customlogout'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\user\Controller\CustomController::custom_logout'
  requirements:
    _user_is_logged_in: 'TRUE'
```

When I visit the **/customlogout** for the **first time** it logs me out of Drupal and redirects me to example.com. If I revisit my site and login in again, and repeat the process it still redirects me to example.com but when I check my site I am still logged in. I am wondering why this happens? I can still logout using /user/logout though

Thank you

Comment: How exactly do you call this function, what function actually, and from where? An event subscriber? Can you please update your question for clarification?

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the question

Comment: I assume that this issue is caused by this line return new TrustedRedirectResponse('https://example.com'). Do we have any alternative that guarantees logout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out,

`return new TrustedRedirectResponse('https://example.com');`

was the culprit here.
TrustedRedirectResponse extends CacheableSecuredRedirectResponse, as a result the function was cached, and user_logout was not called even when I visited the  **/customlogout**

The workaround for this is adding the following lines in your routing.yml

```
options:
    
  no_cache: TRUE
```